# How to get clean, dry marshmellows?

Tags: substitutions

i made marshmellows, came out very well. i cut it and rolled in icing sugar, for a while i was good, but then it stated to absorb the icing sugar and marshmellows are now wet, b ut still in its shape. Can anybody give me a solution to clean, dry texture.
Thanks,
Jubi..

Comment: also see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16195/marshmallows-are-wet-on-the-bottom-as-they-set beside the linked duplicate

Comment: Reading this makes me want to drive to the 24 hr Walmart down the road at this dearthly hour to buy marshmallows.

Answer (score 1):

Marshmallows are full of sugar and often corn syrup, so they are going to be naturally hydrophylic.   If you coat them with powdered sugar, they will eventually absorb it as you have seen.

A better alternative, at least in terms of having them dry to the touch is corn starch (cornflower in the UK), or if they are comparable with the flavor, cocoa.

Of course, neither of these taste as good straight so they give a slight starchy or bitter impression when biting into the marshmallow.